# Cucumber Parallel Testing giving weird results

Tags: maven, selenium, parallel-processing, cucumber, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm trying to run my cucumber project (two runner classes) in parallel browsers and I am getting weird results. When I do a `mvn verify`,  first it will run each runner class sequentially. The first will pass and the second will fail due to the following error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
```

Then right after, it will run both runner classes in parallel (like I want it to), and all will pass just fine. And maven will report the Build Success.

I am not initializing the webdriver in the `@Before` annotation. Instead I am using cucumber-picocontainer dependency injection right into my step definition classes. I have tried swapping driver.close() and driver.quit() in my `@After` annotation, but that didn't change the results. Please find some code snippets below and then my POM. Many thanks in advance.

```
public class GivenSteps {

    WebDriver driver;
    CustomWaits waits;

    public GivenSteps(DependencyInjection dependencyInjection) {
        this.driver = dependencyInjection.getDriver();
        this.waits = dependencyInjection.getWaits();
    }
```

Hooks -

```
    public class Hooks {

        WebDriver driver;

        public Hooks(DependencyInjection dependencyInjection) {
            this.driver = dependencyInjection.getDriver();
        }

        @Before("@setup")
        public void setUp() {

            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
         @After("@destroy")
         public void tearDown() throws Throwable {
          //driver.close();
            driver.quit();
    }
```

Dependency Injection -

```
public class DependencyInjection {

    private static String browserType = Settings.BROWSER.getValue();
    private static WebDriver driver = null;
    private static CustomWaits waits = null;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            driver = utilities.DriverFactory.createDriver(browserType);
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

POM.xml -

```
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <includes>
                            <exclude>
                                **/*Runner.java
                            </exclude>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generateRunners</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <glue>
                                    <package>test.java.stepDefinitions</package>
                                </glue>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                                <featuresDirectory>src/test/resource/</featuresDirectory>
                                <cucumberOutputDir>target/Reports/</cucumberOutputDir>
                                <namingPattern>Runner{c}</namingPattern>
                                <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per 
                                    scenario. FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                                <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>acceptance-test</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*Runner.class</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to comment out the section in my POM.xml -> `maven-surefire-plugin` because now I am only using `maven-failsafe-plugin`

Originally I had both active in my POM, so both were running sequentially.